# Is there any equivalent command for !findstack to filter the managed code?

Tags: windbg

I found the `!findstack` just can be used to filter unmanaged code, however it failed to filter managed code, so is there any equivalent command  for `!findstack` to filter the managed code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a ready-to-use function like this, so I see two options here:

- fiddle around with some WinDbg internal commands (which you can hardly understand half a year later)
- use [PyKd](https://pykd.codeplex.com/) and write a nice script in Python

Approach a)

This may look similar to this:

```
~*e .foreach(word {!clrstack}) {.if ($spat("${word}", "?*RunMessageLoop?*") == 1) {.printf "Found!\n"}}
```

Approach b)

Put the following into a file called `clrfindstack.py`

```
from pykd import *
import sys

if len(sys.argv) == 1: # script name only
    print "Please provide a search string as argument"
    exit()
threads = getNumberThreads()
for thread in range(0, threads):
    dbgCommand("~"+str(thread)+"s")  # select the thread
    stack = dbgCommand("!clrstack")  # run !clrstack
    if sys.argv[1] in stack: # [0] is the script name
        print "Found", sys.argv[1], "in thread", thread, "(Use ~"+str(thread)+"s to select it)"
```

And then run it

```
0:000> !py c:\tmp\clrfindstack.py
Please provide a search string as argument
0:000> !py c:\tmp\clrfindstack.py RunMessageLoop
Found RunMessageLoop in thread 0 (Use ~0s to select it)
```

The implementation is probably not very pythonic, but does its job.